# MySQL stored procedure problem. Throws warning. Cant figure out why?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling, warnings

I have a stored procedure that works for applicant data insert/update actions. Update actions do work fine. But insert queries do come up with errorFlag as 2, which indicates a warning. I just cant figure out what the warning is.

Here is my SP.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mydb.insertApplicant $$

CREATE PROCEDURE mydb.insertApplicant(

                                    IN appFirstName VARCHAR(128),
                                    IN appLastName VARCHAR(128),
                                    IN appEmail VARCHAR(128),
                                    IN appPhone VARCHAR(16),
                                    IN appZipcode VARCHAR(16),
                                    IN appCity VARCHAR(32),
                                    IN appState VARCHAR(32),
                                    IN appCountry VARCHAR(32))
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE appAction VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE applicantId INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE updateFlag INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE errorFlag INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE errorQuery VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT NULL;

    /* Set continue handler for sql exception */
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        SET errorFlag = 1;
    END;

    /* Set continue handler for sql warning */
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
    BEGIN
        SET errorFlag = 2;
    END;

    /* Turn auto-commit off */
    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;

    /* Start ttsnsaction */
    START TRANSACTION;

    /* Set savepoint. If an error occurs, we will rollback to this point */
    SAVEPOINT Savepoint_S1;

    MAIN_BLOCK:BEGIN

        /* Check if applicant already exists */
        SELECT applicant_id INTO applicantId FROM tblApplicant WHERE email = appEmail;

        /* If applicant already exists, then update applicant details */
        IF (applicantId) THEN

            SET appAction = 'Update';

            /* Update applicant details */
            SET @sqlQuery = CONCAT("UPDATE tblApplicant SET ",
            "first_name = '", appFirstName, "', last_name = '", appLastName,
            "', update_date = NOW(), phone = '", appPhone, "', zipcode = '", appZipcode,
            "', city = '", appCity, "', state = '", appState, 
            "', country = '", appCountry, "' WHERE applicant_id = '", applicantId, "'");

            PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlQuery;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

            /* Set update flag to true */
            SET updateFlag = 1;

        END IF;

        IF(updateFlag <> 1) THEN

            SET appAction = 'Insert';

            /* insert applicant details */
            SET @sqlQuery = CONCAT("INSERT INTO tblApplicant (first_name, last_name, email, reg_date, ",
            "phone, zipcode, city, state, country) VALUES ('",
            appFirstName, "', '", appLastName, "', '", appEmail, "', NOW(), '",
        appPhone, "', '", appZipcode, "', '", appCity, "', '", appState, "', '", appCountry, "')");

            PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlQuery;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

            /* Check if an error has occured */
            IF (errorFlag = 0) THEN
                SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO applicantId;
            END IF;

        END IF;

        /* Check if an error has occured */
        IF errorFlag THEN
            ROLLBACK TO Savepoint_S1;
            SELECT @sqlQuery INTO errorQuery;
            LEAVE MAIN_BLOCK;
        END IF;

    END; /* MAIN_BLOCK ends here */

    /* Commit changes if any */
    COMMIT;

    /* Turn auto-commit ON */
    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1;

    /* Select paramters */
    SELECT errorFlag, errorQuery, appAction, applicantId;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Well, you could try `SHOW WARNINGS` after executing the procedure; or you simply remove the CONTINUE HANDLER for SQLWARNING and try again.

Comment: SHOW WARNINGS doesn't show anything after the stored procedure execution. Also, if I use the 'errorQuery' string and run it on console, there is no warning. Insert/Update action works just fine. Its the SP that is throwing a warning. I am just trying to figure out the reason behind it. I can remove the HANDLER for SQLWARNING, but then I will not be able to catch it up later.

Comment: On my MySQL server warnings and notifications from stored procedures go to the error log. On Debian it is located in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` but you can determine the location on your system by doing `SELECT @@log_error;`. Have you checked your error log for any messages?

Answer (score 1):

Use GET DIAGNOSTICS

See
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html

Comment: Whoever down voted this: check again, GET DIAGNOSTICS is the correct answer. If for some reason you *think* it is not the solution, please explain why ...

Comment: Perhaps it was downvoted because GET DIAGNOSTICS is only available in 5.6. However, the original poster didn't specify version; so, the answer is still a good one.